# How can I use the roblox image API to show an image from a url paramater in php?

Tags: php

I have been trying to get an image thumbnail from the ROBLOX API in php. The image works if I just put in the image in the code, but using a URL parameter, it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$p = $_GET['image_url'];
$a = file_get_contents($p);
echo $a;
```

The kind of link this is is `http://www.roblox.com/asset-thumbnail/image?assetId=(AssetId)&width=420&height=420&format=png`

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

```php
$cURLConnection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.roblox.com/asset-thumbnail/image?assetId=(AssetId)&width=420&height=420&format=png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-type: image/jpeg;');

$roblox= curl_exec($cURLConnection);

curl_close($cURLConnection);

$jsonArrayResponse - json_decode($roblox);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.